# kqoauth including

Tags: qt

I have downloaded [kqoauth](https://www.gitorious.org/kqoauth/kqoauth). I had a really hard time to include it in my project.

Finally, I used its .dll and added it using `LIBS += -itsDLL`.

It was working great on the simulator.

However, when I try to deploy for the symbian, building fails and the error is:

```
warning: Missing dependency detected:
 C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/kqoauthd0.dso
```

My problem is that there is no trace of such `.dso` file!? What is this?

## Extra error details:

```
:-1: error: Recipe linkandpostlink failed with exit code 1.
```

---

```
:-1: Running command: C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/tools/checklib.exe stdc++ --elf C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/qtmain.lib
Running command: C:/QtSDK/Symbian/tools/gcce4/bin/arm-none-symbianelf-g++.exe -Wl,-Ttext,0x8000 -Wl,--no-undefined -nodefaultlibs -Wl,-shared -Wl,-Tdata,0x400000 -Wl,--default-symver '-Wl,-soname=dubizzle{000a0000}[e5f5fb1c].exe' -Wl,--entry=_E32Startup -Wl,-u,_E32Startup,C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/eexe.lib -o C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/dubizzle.exe.sym -Wl,-Map=C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/dubizzle.exe.map @C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/build/dubizzle/c_aad491c882e3389e/dubizzle_exe/armv5/udeb/dubizzle_udeb_objects.via --start-group C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/usrt3_1.lib --end-group C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/usrt3_1.lib C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/udeb/qtmain.lib C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/kqoauthd0.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/libstdcppv5.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/QtDeclarative.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/QtGui.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/QtNetwork.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/QtCore.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/libpthread.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/libc.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/libm.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/euser.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/libdl.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/stdnew.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/drtaeabi.dso C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/dfpaeabi.dso -lsupc++ -lgcc
arm-none-symbianelf-g++.exe: C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/kqoauthd0.dso: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved !!!
The problem was that I am including a .dll library, this works great for the simulator but not for the device, so the idea was to include all .h and .cpp files if the target is a symbian device, and the .dll library if the target is the simulator.